# Torchlight 2 Passive Spells

Tags: torchlight-2

So there are passive spells in Torchlight 2 that I can use on either me or my pet. If I use them on my pet, will I get the effects or just my pet? If I use them on myself, will I get the effect and not my pet?

Answer (score 6):

[Torchlight wiki](http://torchlight.wikia.com/wiki/Spells_%28T2%29) states:

> Tomes equipped on a pet convey their passive benefits to the pet only;
>   apparently passives like increased magic item find are **not** relayed
>   back to the player.

Spells like Animal Handling used on you will have effect on pet as stated in its description.

Comment: If it helped, mark question as answered :)